# How can I convert class based project to function based?

Tags: react-native

I am too beginner in react-native. But I am given a project thats done in React Native in class based components... I am wanted to convert it in function based.
I studied react native from youtube video for a few days... But  i cant understand about how to change it.

its a company project, and it seems so difficult for me to get it done.

The only thing i did is , I added seperated routeNames file, because it was inside a main file. So i import it from there.

I Know i will delete words like "this", "this.props", "render" . Thats all i know of. but im sure it wont work only doing that.

Can anyone help me to understand this?

Here is some part of the main file:

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext(null);
export class GlobalContextProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    JSON: '.json?cache=2',
    isDebug: true,
    currentTheme: 'light',
    isKeyboardOpen: false,
    isBottomSheetOpen: false,
    showSplash: true,
    showLoginRegister: true,
    inAction: false,
    uploading: false, // used infolder uploading section
    isUploading: false,
    userToken: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    userData: {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      email: '',
      accountType: '',
      remaining: 0,
      quota: 0,
      corporate: '',
      apiKEY: '',
      apiURL: '',
    },
    folderData: [],
    receiptData: [],
    currentData: {},
    baseEmptyData: {
      receiptID: -1,
      processID: 0,
      receiptName: "",
      image: "",
      hasImage: 0,
      inputs: {
        companyName: '',
        fisNo: '',
        fisTarihi: '',
        vd: '',
        vdNo: ''
      },
      extra: [],
      items: [
        {
          urunAdi: '',
          tutar: '',
          kdv: ''
        }
      ]
    },

    toastRef: null,
    sheetRef: null,

    settings: {
      theme: 'light',
      maxYear: 2,
      showEmpty: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow(e) { this.setState({ isKeyboardOpen: true }); }
  _keyboardDidHide() { setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ isKeyboardOpen: false }); }, 200) }

  setBottomSheet = (val) => { this.setState({ isBottomSheetOpen: val }); }
  /* MISC BEGIN */
  Log = (...args) => { if (this.state.isDebug) { console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(args).join(" ")); } }
  loadSettings = async (callback) => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('settings');
      if (data !== null) {
        const jData = Object.assign({}, this.state.settings, JSON.parse(data));
        this.setState({ settings: jData, currentTheme: jData.theme }, () => {
          callback();
        });
      } else {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(this.state.settings));
        this.setState({ currentTheme: 'light' }, () => {
          callback();
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      this.Log('loadSettings Error => ', err);
      callback();
    }
  }
  saveSettings = async (key, value, callback) => {
    try {
      let jData = this.state.settings;
      jData[key] = value;
      this.Log(jData);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(jData));
      this.setState({ settings: jData }, () => {
        if (callback != undefined) {
          callback();
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      this.Log('saveSettings Error => ', err);
      if (callback != undefined) {
        callback();
      }
    }
  }
```

This is navigation file:

```
class Navigator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() { }
  render() {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar barStyle={'light-content'} translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} />
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }} >
            {this.props.global.showSplash ? (
              <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} />
            ) : (
              this.props.global.showLoginRegister ? (
                <Stack.Screen name="LoginRegisterScreen" component={LoginRegister} />
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="FolderScreen" component={FolderScreen} initialParams={{ folderID: 0 }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} initialParams={{ isNew: true, isEditable: true, folderID: 0, receiptID: 0, hasImage: true }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
                </>
              )
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default withGlobalContext(Navigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
export default class MyPlaceholderScreen extends React.Component {
        
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
    }
        
    async loadData() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, data: 'myData' });
    }

    render() {
       <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
    }
}
```

will change to:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
const MyPlaceholderScreen = (props) => {
    
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, []); // if passing empty array as a parameter, the function inside useEffect will run only after first render, if no parameter is passed, the function inside will run after every re-render (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
        
    const loadData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setData('myData');
    }

    return(
        <Text>{data}</Text>
    )
}
    
export default MyPlaceholderScreen;
```

class lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount()` do not exist in function based components, it is replaced with `useEffect()` hook, learn more about this at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

i've posted this answer before, but you deleted the question

Comment: Hello, sorry Sir. I thought when you were answering i just deleted the question when i thought there were not answer. Because when there is an answer, this site doesnt let us delete the question if I am not mistaken. Now im gonna review your code. Thank you a lot.

Comment: yeah it got deleted right before i pressed button to post the answer :D

Comment: ı couldnt do anything with that code. When i see the example code you posted, i think it seems easy. But when i look at the codes in the project i asked, it becomes too difficult for me:(

Comment: Do you have any chance to look at codes i posted , so you may give me hints.. ?

Comment: I am not getting an error. But i dont know where to start and i dont know what to change and what to write. For example;  `const GlobalContext = React.createContext({}); 
export const GlobalContextProvider = () => {}`   then im done, i cant continue...:/

Comment: state= {} -> for this part, i think  i can make seperate file, named initialStates.js and put all stuff inside. But after that,  starting from componentDidMount() {} i dont know what to write for those parts.

Comment: for example `_keyboardDidShow(e) { this.setState({ isKeyboardOpen: true }); }`  is gonna look like `const _keyboardDidShow = (e) => { setKeyboardOpen(true) } `

Comment: So this means, i should add `const [keyboardOpen, setKeyboardOpen]=useState(false);` before `const _keyboardDidShow(e). ` Am i right?

Comment: yes, useState replaced this.state in function components

Comment: how about this two parts Sir, https://snack.expo.io/-bw3mdcSN   how to change it into function based? Can you help.